# Mathematica- Assumptions within Simplify[]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplify

I am using the ratio between two error probabilities in various functions. I want Mathematica to display this ratio in the most simple manner. How do I let Mathematica know that, in this case, the simplest manner is as the top line in the picture below?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/89eol.png]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, if you want help, include the code in the question, not as a link!

Answer (score 0):

```
      (1-e1)/(1-e2) // TraditionalForm
```

Be aware this is strictly for output formatting, so for example if you do

```
       x=TraditionalForm[(1-e1)/(1-e2)]   ! prints nice

       x === (1-e1)/(1-e2)  ->  False
```

That said, as a general principle you'll get much more done if you quit loosing sleep over mathematica's sometimes unusual formatting..

Comment: Thank you. However, for some more complicated functions using this ratio, it still does not print the way I want it to, and that should be the most obvious, simple manner. For example: TraditionalForm[Simplify[(1 - e1)/(1 - e1 + e2)]] does not print nice.

Comment: Ultimately its tough to teach the computer what *you* think looks right. In any case you should take this up on mathematica.stackexchange.com